# Указатели в С++

Tags: c++

Как понять указатели?

Comment: Указатель указывает на конкретную область памяти, вот и всё.

Comment: @Rasul, Поясните, что именно вам не понятно.

Comment: Указатель - это просто адрес памяти, номер ячейки в памяти. Все.

Comment: Это которые `pointer`, обозначаются звёздочкой в описании типа и являются результатом операции "взять адрес" `&`: `int *a = &b;`, или которые `reference` (в описании методов `int& a`)?

Comment: Те, "которые reference (в описании методов int& a)", называются "ссылками"

Comment: Только вот гарантии, что термин "ссылка" не будет использован при упоминании "указателя", никто не даст. Особенно если человек будет читать книжку не по C++

Comment: Так это был сарказм?

Comment: ну для начала нужно понять главное -- ложки не существует...

Answer (score 7):

Допустим у Вас программа:

```
int n = 1234;  // переменная
int *p = &n;   // указатель (тоже является переменной)
int m = 5678;
```

И представим память (адрес байта:значение *весьма условно*)

```
............
1000 : 1   // это начало памяти, отведенной под переменную n
1001 : 2   // в этих 4-х байтах с 100 по 103 находится число 1234
1002 : 3
1003 : 4
1004 : 1   // это начало памяти, отведенной под указатель p
1005 : 0   // в ней (для 32-х разрядного процессора тоже 4 байта)
1006 : 0   // находится число 1000, это АДРЕС переменной n в памяти
1007 : 0
1008 : 5   // а это переменная m (число 5678)
1009 : 6
1010 : 7
1011 : 8
```

Если теперь в программе написать:

```
*p = m;
```

то значение переменной **m** (5678) запишется по адресу (он равен 1000 в нашем примере), содержащимся в указателе **p** и станет новым значением переменной **n**. Получим:

```
1000:5678
1004:1000
1008:5678
```

Надеюсь, теперь все стало понятно.

Answer (score 2):

Если переносить указатели на реальную жизнь, то показывая пальцем на шкаф или дом, вы тем самым *указываете* "вон тот шкаф" или "вон тот дом". А если возвращаться в программирование, то указатель - это адрес в памяти, который указывает на конкретный участок в памяти.

Answer (score 1):

Указатель - переменная, содержащая адрес, *указывающий* на то место в памяти, где лежат данные. 
Нужны:

- для того, чтобы индексировать массивы
- указывать на объекты, для которых точно неизвестно какого они типа
- передавать адрес, чтобы можно было изменять данные из других мест (например, функций)
- другие нужды, ну да не будем о них пока

Answer (score 0):

В.В.Подбельский "Язык С++", М."Финансы и статистика", 1999 г. Очень хорошая книга.

Comment: Уважаемому @Илья Михневич следовало бы самому разобраться с указателями прежде, чем давать советы.

Answer (score 0):

Любая переменная, структура, объект и т.д. представляют собой последовательность байтов в памяти, т.е. ячеек, в которых хранится какая-то информация. Указатель - это переменная, в которой содержится адрес какой-то другой переменной или иного типа данных. Следуя этому адресу, программа может получить доступ к этим данным.

Answer (score 0):

для начала, нужно понять главное -- ложки не существует.